# GurobiError: No Gurobi license found

Tags: optimization, gurobi

I'm attempting to run an example jupyter notebook from Gurobi:
https://github.com/Gurobi/modeling-examples/blob/master/factory_planning/factory_planning_1.ipynb

I have installed gurobipy, but when I try to run the line `factory = gp.Model('Factory Planning I')` I receive an error message, `GurobiError: No Gurobi license found`.

I thought that gurobipy had a limited-variables option if you do not have a license, and that this option would at least allow me to run the example problems. Could you please help me learn how to run this example problem?

Unfortunately, Gurobi's support page was not helpful on this topic.
https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/14971798307345-How-do-I-resolve-the-error-No-Gurobi-license-found

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

# tested with Python 3.7.0 & Gurobi 9.0

# Import data, snipped for brevity, see link above

factory = gp.Model('Factory Planning I')
```

And when starting the gp.Model, that is when I receive the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use pip to install gurobipy, it comes with a free size-limited license. Most likely, you installed gurobipy from another source like the standard Gurobi distribution.

Comment: Thanks.  If I try `!pip install gurobipy` now, I receive the message `Requirement already satisfied: gurobipy in /Users/alberta/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (9.1.2)`.  When I try the same script above, I have the same message as before.  Is there a way to uninstall and reinstall that might be required perhaps?

Comment: I attempted to update my version of `gurobipy` in case that may have been my issue, but upon trying that I realized that `anaconda3` was my issue as it was preventing the upgrade.  I read of another user that had a similar issue with `anaconda3` so I uninstalled it and reinstalled everything with `pip`.  Now gurobipy works for me with the `Gurobi Optimizer version 11.0.1 build v11.0.1rc0 (mac64[x86] - Darwin 21.2.0 21C52)`.  Thanks again for the reply.